# How can I grab interim objects generated for operations, types, messages while processing WSDL/XSD files using Apache CXF?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to process WSDL file using Apache CXF. How can I grab the interim objects generated for types, operations etc so that I can process them later. I'm using the tool for helping me with parsing the given WSDL/XSD file only.